# Node.jsでZIPファイルを展開したい

Tags: node.js

ZIPファイルと展開先ディレクトリのパスを与えるとZIPの中身が宛先ディレクトリの中に全部展開される、という処理をしたいです。良い方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unzipというnpmモジュールがあります。

https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip

このように利用します。

```
var fs = require('fs');
var unzip = require('unzip');

fs.createReadStream('./xxx.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'output/path' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

普通にコマンドを叩けます

```
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
execSync('unzip file_path dir_path');
```